# Problems with javascript object and animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, jquery-animate

I've been fooling around with JavaScript/JQuery, and decided to create a little program which would animate a ball bouncing around a rectangular boundary area. I believe that the logic of my code should make sense, but for some reason I can't get it to change directions. What is even stranger is that I put the ball's x and y positions as text on it, but it seems statically stuck (it doesn't change), but I see when I inspect the element that it's left and top css parameters are changing over time.

Here's the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <style>
            .ball {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                background: red;
                -moz-border-radius: 50px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
                border-radius: 50px;
                position: absolute;
            }
            .boundary {
                width: 700px;
                height: 500px;
                background: #AAAAAA;
                border-style:solid;
                border-width:5px;
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var b = new ball(1, 1, 10, 10);
                for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    b.moveBall();
            });

            function ball(xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel)
            {
                this.xPos = xPos;
                this.yPos = yPos;
                this.xVel = xVel;
                this.yVel = yVel;
                this.rightBound = false
                this.leftBound = false;
                this.upBound = false;
                this.downBound = false;
                this.width = 50;
                this.height = 50;


                this.moveBall = moveBall;
                function moveBall()
                {
                    var h = 500;
                    var w = 700;

                    //detect if it is at x bounds
                    if(this.xPos + this.width + this.xVel > w)
                        {this.rightBound = true;}
                    else if(this.xPos + this.xVel < -1)
                        this.leftBound = true;
                    else
                    {
                        this.rightBound = false;
                        this.leftBound = false;
                    }

                    //detect if it is at y bounds
                    if(this.yPos + this.height + this.yVel > h)
                        {this.downBound = true;}
                    else if(this.yPos + this.yVel < -1)
                        this.upBound = true;
                    else
                    {
                        this.upBound = false;
                        this.downBound = false;
                    }

                    //handle velocity changes for bounds
                    //so you switch the x direction if x bound is met, same for y
                    if(this.rightBound || this.leftBound)
                        this.xVel *= -1;
                    if(this.upBound || this.downBound)
                        this.yVel *= -1;

                    //now give motion               
                    this.xPos += xVel;
                    this.yPos += yVel;

                    //now draw  
                    $(".ball").animate({
                        left:this.xPos + 'px',
                        top:this.yPos + 'px'
                        }, 150).text(this.xPos + "," + this.yPos);  
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="boundary">
            <div class="ball"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The weird thing is that it seems to automatically put the end value of 10,001, 10,001 (assuming it never changes direction) as it's (x,y) coordinates from the very beginning. Anything that could point me in the right direction would be appreciated! And sorry if it's some basic error, I tried to ensure it wasn't but sometimes they slip through!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing your `ball.moveBall` in a loop, not on a timer.  So it's going as fast as computably possible.  Yes, computably isn't a word.  Moving on.

By calling `$.animate` you're saying you want jQuery to handle moving the object from one spot to another.  jQuery goes way way way way way slower than the computer.  Hang on, this is getting confusing.  Let me put it simply.

You loop through `ball.moveBall` 1000 times.  How long does that take?  Virtually no time at all.  That's why the coordinates stay stuck at 1000 the whole time.  It actually gets there super super super fast.  So fast, it gets there basically before jQuery has time to start moving the ball.  And.... then the ball starts moving.  Why?  Why doesn't it actually move to position 1000,1000 right away?  Well, the coordinates do get to 1000,1000.  But jQuery is like, "Oh, okay, move the ball to position 1000,1000.  I can do that!  Really really slowly...".  You're probably tired of hearing the explanation, so here's the fix:

Change `$(".ball").animate` to `$(".ball").css`.  And change your loop to `window.setInterval(function(){b.moveBall()},1000)` or something like that.  I've set up a fiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/uXbwR/

You'll notice it moves really slowly.  That's cause I set the interval to 1000 milliseconds, which means it only moves once every second.  For a game you'll want something like 1000/60 (once every 60th of a second), but I tried that and it makes the ball move super fast.  You've got the ball's speed really high.  You might wanna try turning that down a bit.

That's all I've got.

**Edit**

Computationally.  That's the word I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the best solution. I actually found the reason that it wasn't bouncing was because I missed an object reference to the velocity.
    //now give motion               
    this.xPos += xVel;
    this.yPos += yVel;
should have this.xVel, this.yVel. However, as you stated, this doesn't fix the basic problem of it updating. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: No problem.  Also, I noticed you can keep the .animate function if you want, just make sure (as stated in @Andrea's answer) that you mess around with the timing so it isn't too slow.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the next step of the animation only when the preceding has completed. You are telling animate to take 150ms, but the while loop completes almost instantly, without waiting each step.

[EDIT]

@Samuel answer is complete and already suggested you a good workaround. I guess this is going to be beyond the purposes of your application, but if you're interested in setting up a proper Javascript game mainloop these are some useful resources followed by an implementation of mine:

Fabien Sanglard, [Game timers: Issues and solutions](http://fabiensanglard.net/timer_and_framerate/index.php)

Paul Irish, [requestAnimationFrame for smart animating](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/).

```
var RENDERING_FRAME_TIME = 1000/60; // ms
var PHYSICS_FRAME_TIME = 5;         // ms

var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
var accumulator = 0;

(function mainloop(){
    newTime = new Date().getTime();
    accumulator = newTime - currentTime;
    currentTime = newTime;
    while (accumulator > PHYSICS_FRAME_TIME) {
        integrate(PHYSICS_FRAME_TIME);
        accumulator -= PHYSICS_FRAME_TIME;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainloop);
    render();
})();
```